# JPA merge does not work on first time but works on second time

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, merge, ejb-3.0

I know this is very common and there are a lot of questions asked regarding the merge not updating data in the database. But this is a bit different.

From front end When I click on the save button I can see the data in CaseSpecimen is updated for all the three attributes, But when the merge is called on this object, It does not update the DB. After the response is returned and If I click on the save button again as the field has the data which I want, After the merge is called on the CaseSpecimen object again, this time it saves the data in Database.

And this is happening only for one specimen type. 
Let say we have 2 specimen types A and B against Case c.
If I update the values in Type A and click on Save it will update the data in the database. But if I do exactly the same for Type B, It won't update the data for the first time but If I click on the save button the second time, then the values will be updated in the database.

SpecModel.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CASE_SPECIMEN")
@NamedQuery(name = "CaseSpecimen.findAll", query = "SELECT c FROM CaseSpecimen c")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CaseSpecimen extendsBaseEntity implements Serializable, 
Comparable<CaseSpecimen> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "SPECIMEN_BODY_SITE")
    private String bodySite;

    @Column(name = "SPECIMEN_PROCEDURE")
    private String procedureName;

    @Column(name = "SPECIMEN_SOURCE")
    private String specimenSource;

   ... 
   getters and setters
}
```

Main Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`CASE`")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Case extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {
public static final String CASE_CODE_SEPERATOR = "-";

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "CASE_ID")
   @GsonIgnore
   @XmlTransient
   private int id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patientCase", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST })
   @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
   private Set<CaseSpecimen> caseSpecimens;

   ...
   getters and setters
}
```

Case Dao:

```
@Singleton
public class CaseDao extends GenericEntityDAO<PendingList> {
    @PersistenceContext(name = "APP_DB")
    protected EntityManager entityManager; 

    public CaseSpecimen updateCaseSpecimen(CaseSpecimen specimen) {
        return entityManager.merge(specimen);
    }
}
```

even I have called the flush method after merge but still no update in DB

```
  public CaseSpecimen updateCaseSpecimen(CaseSpecimen specimen) {
        CaseSpecimen spec = entityManager.merge(specimen);
        entityMannger.flush();
        return spec;
  }
```

Controller:

```
 for (CaseSpecimen specimen : case.getCaseSpecimens()) {
    ... if the updated object from front end the below line will execute
    caseSpecimensUpdatedList.add(caseService.updateCaseSpecimen(specimen));
}
```

**CaseService: Currently it's an extra layer. this just calls the Dao Method.**

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
        <persistence-unit name="APP_DB"  >
             <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/AppDataSource</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:/AppEntityManager"/>
        <property name="wildfly.jpa.default-unit" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="100"/>
        <property name="hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer" value="allow"/>

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Do you get an exception? And did you check the generated SQL statements? Additionally you are in a Java EE container. Your DAO should be Stateless not a Singleton becuase the EntityManager is not thread safe

Comment: @SimonMartinelli No, I'm not getting any kind of exception. I tried but there is a lot going on before reaching this statement. So even if I enable logging It's ambiguous which select and update statement run for this specific merge.  Regarding Singleton I know it should be stateless I currently can't go with change before getting approval.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and have not a clue what happens and how to solve it.

Comment: @Dmitry Upon thorough investigation and debugging line by line, we found out that another method was called, in which save was again called but it was on old data and both of them were in the same transaction block that's why it was doing cause the above behavior.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation of *merge* you will find that:

> Merge the state of the given entity into the current persistence context.

This doesn't means that the database will update immediately! The persistence context acts as a transactional write-behind cache, queuing any entity state change. Like any write-behind cache, changes are first applied in-memory and synchronized with the database during flush time. The flush operation takes every entity state change and translates it to an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement.

Indeed the *flush* documentation says that:

> Synchronize the persistence context to the underlying database.

This is obviously true inside the current transaction. Out of there no change is visible until the transaction commit.

If the flush isn't explicitly invokated, the persistence provider follows a strategy that could have different settings: AUTO or COMMIT.

Again the documentation of *FlushModType* says that:

> When queries are executed within a transaction, if FlushModeType.AUTO is set on the 
>    Query or TypedQuery object, or if the flush mode setting for the persistence context is AUTO (the default) and a flush mode setting has not been specified for the Query or TypedQuery object, the persistence provider is responsible for ensuring that all updates to the state of all entities in the persistence context which could potentially affect the result of the query are visible to the processing of the query. The persistence provider implementation may achieve this by flushing those entities to the database or by some other means.
>
> If FlushModeType.COMMIT is set, the effect of updates made to entities in the persistence context upon queries is unspecified.

Comment: I have updated the question. I already explicitly called the flush method to check whether it will update the data in DB or not But still no changes in DB.

Comment: It may depend on whether the class is a Singleton ... on transaction managment. Let's try to use a JTA directive as  `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` on method `updateCaseSpecimen`

Comment: I used what you suggested, I tried making the Class as stateless, Still, it does not update the data on the first click on save button. As soon as I click the second time it does update the data

Comment: What about the Transaction directive? Are you sure that the method are invoked every time you click the button?

Comment: Used the Directive also, But still, the same result, data in DB does not change.  CaseSpecimen spec = entityManager.merge(specimen); The spec object is the contains old data, I know this spec object is now a managed object but it has old data instead of the new data which I want to update